# Remove EditText context menu color

Tags: android

I'm using `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`.
I want to remove the accent color from the context menu items show in the picture:
[image: EditText context menu accent color]

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your app theme `android:panelBackground=@android:color/transparent`

Comment: I edited the question and added which theme I'm using.